# An error that is considered very irrational

Tags: c#, asp.net, backend

I encountered a problem, I thought a lot, I did not get anywhere. I have a table in the database called ticket, which contains the tickets and the answer to the tickets. I proceed with the repository model. I wrote a function that takes the ticket ID and extracts the text.
NullReferenceException gives an error when I try to get the value. If I tried with brakepoint, the value was sent. Even if I checked with if, it says the value was sent.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iuV9.png)

Comment: Please add your code/data/error as text to your question (and pay attention to [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)). There are [many good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), why images of code are not a good idea.

Comment: We cant debug a story

Answer (score -2):

Your view model property is null. That's why Answer.AnswerText cause a NullReferenceException because Answer is null.